# Facebook Multiple Like Buttons On A Single Page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails

I have a page where I need to have about 3 Facebook Like buttons.

They all Like different urls.

How can i select different profile images (one that will be shown on facebook) for each Like Button.

Any Help?

Comment: Are those different like buttons all pointing to the same URL? Then it’s _not_ possible, OG meta info is tied to a URL.

Comment: No all like buttons are pointing to different URL.

Comment: Then where’s the problem? Set different OG meta tags on each of those URLs.

Comment: But all the like buttons are on same page?

Comment: So what? It does not matter where a like button is _embedded_, but where it _points_ to.

Comment: @CBroe - I have some confusions about that. Actually i have multiple like buttons for different urls on a single web page. can you show me show examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem my own way.

What I did is...

1. > Pass an extra parameter along with url to be liked. The parameter
   >   contains an unique identifier for that link.
2. > Check for the parameter on every request of that page. If found then set Meta Tags accordingly.

Comment: you didnt, @CBroe above did

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnails for the like buttons to other pages are set by the og.image on the other url.

So, if you like example.com/puppies, FB uses the OG data from that url no matter where you are.

---

From http://ogp.me/

To turn your web pages into graph objects, you need to add basic metadata to your page. We've based the initial version of the protocol on RDFa which means that you'll place additional  tags in the  of your web page. The four required properties for every page are:

og:title - The title of your object as it should appear within the graph, e.g., "The Rock".

og:type - The type of your object, e.g., "video.movie". Depending on the type you specify, other properties may also be required.

og:image - An image URL which should represent your object within the graph.

og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/".

Comment: I have some confusions about that. Actually i have multiple like buttons for different urls on a single web page. can you show me show examples on how to do this?

Comment: In the header of each separate page on your site that you have a life button FOR you needed to add the open graph data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/#publish

Comment: But i have two like buttons on each separate page??

Comment: Doesn't matter. They will use the data from the actual URL you are liking.

Answer (score -3):

Sample code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxx";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example1.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example2.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example3.com" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Comment: How to select images for this like buttons?